# scrape a list of links in beautiful soup using range

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been practicing my web scraping skills and came across a problem that involved me filtering though a set of 10 links by grabbing the paragraph tag with id="secret-word". I figured out how to do it for the first link so I thought it would be good to loop though the processes and grab them all at once.

Here is the website that I'm grabbing the links from (links located at the bottom): https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html

This is the code that I came up with..but I cant figure out how to get element 0 (n=0) without separating it from the while loop. Maybe you can't?

**I pulled a list of all the links:**

```
new_listc = links_with_text1[19:]

['challenge/file_1.html',
 'challenge/file_2.html',
 'challenge/file_3.html',
 'challenge/file_4.html',
 'challenge/file_5.html',
 'challenge/file_6.html',
 'challenge/file_7.html',
 'challenge/file_8.html',
 'challenge/file_9.html',
 'challenge/file_10.html']
```

**I connected to each site using requests:**

```
t = [requests.get(f"https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/{url}", timeout=5) for url in new_listc]
```

**I looped all the links though beautiful soup and grabbed the secret word from each link to get the list of words. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this and why I had to put the first challenge file outside the loop?!**

```
 n=0
    tsoup = bs(t[n].content)  
        
    test_soup = tsoup.select("p#secret-word")
    #print(n)
    x = [t.text for t in test_soup]
    print(x)
    while n in range(0,9):
        n += 1
        #print(n)
        tsoup = bs(t[n].content)  
        test_soup = tsoup.select("p#secret-word")
        x = [t.text for t in test_soup]
        print(x)
        #print(tsoup.prettify())
        if n > 9:
            break

['Make']
['sure']
['to']
['smash']
['that']
['like']
['button']
['and']
['subscribe']
['!!!']
```

Comment: This solved it!: 
`code
for n in range(len(oo)):
    count = count + oo[n]
    tsoup = bs(t[n].content)  
    test_soup = tsoup.select("p#secret-word")  
    for y in test_soup:
        print(y.text) 
code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, there's really nothing wrong with your approach, and by "a cleaner way" you ask for people's preferences, IMHO. So, here's mine.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_content(number: int) -> str:
    url = f"https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/challenge/file_{number}.html"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url).text, "html.parser"
    ).select_one("p#secret-word")
    return soup.getText(strip=True)


print(" ".join(get_content(number) for number in range(1, 11)))
```

Output:

```
Make sure to smash that like button and subscribe !!!
```

The above answer assumes there are `10` pages to loop over, but if you need to scrape the main one first, I'd try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

the_url = "https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html"


def make_soup_first(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")


def get_follow_links(main_link: str) -> list:
    soup = make_soup_first(main_link)
    return [
        a["href"] for a in soup.find_all(
            lambda t: t.name == "a" and "File" in t.text
        )
    ]


def get_content(follow_link: str) -> str:
    url = f"https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/{follow_link}"
    return make_soup_first(url).select_one("p#secret-word").getText(strip=True)


print(" ".join(get_content(link) for link in get_follow_links(the_url)))
```

Which give the same output as above:

```
Make sure to smash that like button and subscribe !!!
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I like how you broke it up into functions as well because it makes it so much easier to follow and stay cleaner!!! I'm going to work on organizing my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to put the first challenge file outside of your loop is because the first line of your loop increments n by 1, so on its first iteration it accesses `t[1]` rather than `t[0]`. You could fix this by moving that line to the end of your loop, but a cleaner approach would be to use a for loop:

```
tsoup = bs(t[n].content)  
test_soup = tsoup.select("p#secret-word")
for secret_word in test_soup:
    print(secret_word.text)
```